# How to use the apache commons java library on Ubuntu?

Tags: java

I am a Java beginner and trying to figure out how to use the apache commons lib.

Here is a source file `Randstr.java`:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils;

class Randstr {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = RandomStringUtils.random(12);
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

I have the `commons-lang3-3.1.jar` file in /usr/share/java/ and have created a symlink in the current dir. Then I compiled it like this: `javac -cp  commons-lang3-3.1.jar Randstr.java`, the complilation was fine, but when I execute `java Randstr`, I got the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang3/RandomStringUtils
        at Randstr.main(Randstr.java:5)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 1 more
```

And if I don't specify the jar file in the classpath, it will not even compile:

```
javac -cp . Randstr.java

# Randstr.java:1: error: package org.apache.commons.lang3 does not exist
# import org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils;
#                                ^
# Randstr.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
#         String s = RandomStringUtils.random(12);
#                    ^
#   symbol:   variable RandomStringUtils
#   location: class Randstr
# 2 errors

javac -cp /usr/share/java/  Randstr.java

# Randstr.java:1: error: package org.apache.commons.lang3 does not exist
# import org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils;
#                                ^
# Randstr.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
#         String s = RandomStringUtils.random(12);
#                    ^
#   symbol:   variable RandomStringUtils
#   location: class Randstr
# 2 errors
```

From reading other questions on stackoverflow, I see this can be solved by using an IDE, but I prefer a simple editor at the moment.

Comment: This looks like a good question. What did the OP do wrong?

Comment: @Cole"Cole9"Johnson Globally installing a Java library for starters. (Well, not really.) Refusing to use an IDE that can assist in managing the libraries before learning Maven would be second.

Comment: @Cole"Cole9"Johnson I just realised that you were asking about the close vote which I didn't cast. I figure that asking about closes or downvotes is mostly pointless - the person doesn't wish to engage in a dialogue about this, and likely voted and moved on. If they did they'd have written a comment already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can compile it with

```
javac -cp commons-lang3-3.1.jar Randstr.java
```

then you can run it with

```
java -cp commons-lang3-3.1.jar:. Randstr
```

The JAR file has to be in the classpath.

Comment: still no luck, `java -cp commons-lang3-3.1.jar Randstr Error: Could not find or load main class Randstr`

Comment: just add current dir to classpath

Comment: @PlínioPantaleão The current working directory is always on the classpath.

Comment: @millimoose - The working directory is on the classpath by default, once you start messing with classpath you should include it.

Comment: @millimoose This way I can clearly see how it works, while in an IDE these things will be hidden, that's why I am not comfortable with IDE when I am learning an language, it makes me feel as if I am in a blackbox.

Comment: @CravingSpirit Nonetheless in practice you will end up using high-level ways of dealing with this, so from another point of view you're avoiding learning about them. Either way my answer links to the conceptual documentation about this for more background information.

Comment: You need semicolon ';' instead of colon ':' as a delimiter in the classpath for this to work

Answer (score 1):

Edit your profile file. vim ~/.bashrc

In your profile file add the following line:

```bash
export CLASSPATH=/usr/share/java/commons-lang3-3.1.jar:.
```

Log out and back in. Or source your profile file in the windows you have open. You can always add your classpath to every java and javac command you invoke but that becomes a pain. With the CLASSPATH environmental variable you don't have to add it on the command line any more. Note that if you are using an IDE such as NetBeans or Eclipse you still might have to add the library to your project's libraries within the IDE.

Comment: Setting CLASSPATH is not recommended practice.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend changing the system level classpath but the user specific one? For a library like commons and a developer that wants to build by hand? This is one of the few times to recommend the practice.

Comment: It's not actively bad, but it's a stopgap. What I mean is that sooner or later you'll have to learn how to make isolated projects, so I'd say you might as well. (Heck, entire programming language communities took **years** to realise this is something they have to support.)

Answer (score 0):

Clearly the contents of `/usr/share/java/` don't automatically get added to the classpath - it's just a common location where APT packages put Java libraries. It's up the developer to reference them correctly.

JARs in the `ext/` subdirectory of a Java installation do get added to the classpath automatically. However, **do not** put your own JARs in there. It's a terrible practice because it doesn't match how Java apps are deployed "in the real world".

The correct way is using the `-cp` parameter explicitly **when compiling AND running** your app. Java doesn't compile library code into your `.class` files, a `.class` file only refers to names of other classes which are then loaded as-needed from the class path when your app runs. The `-cp` parameter takes only `.jar` files, or directories with `.class` files in them. You can also use wildcards in the value of that parameter. For more information on wrangling the class path, check the [tool documentation on setting the class path](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html).

You using a build tool that sets it for you automatically, like an IDE or [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) or another build system with dependency management. ([Gradle](http://www.gradle.org/) or [Ant+Ivy](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/).) If you're writing a Java app that uses third party libraries, I *very strongly* suggest you learn and use one of those. (Also, most IDEs can work with Maven's configuration files letting you use the same build settings in a team with people using mixed or no IDEs.) Generally if you're invoking a compiler directly you're not doing it right.

Comment: But he made a simlink putting the jar in the same folder as the source

Comment: @anakata So? It doesn't matter where the JAR is if you don't specify it on the classpath. I edited my answer to emphasise that you need to do it when running the app now.

Comment: but he is doing it isn't he ? **javac -cp commons-lang3-3.1.jar Randstr.java**

Comment: @anakata When compiling, which works - "the complilation was fine". Then the app crashes when they run it with the command line `java Randstr` - without the necessary `-cp`.